# minify html, css and js on nginx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, minify

I was looking for a good way to minifying my css, js and html codes, and found this package at google https://code.google.com/p/minify/. The issue that I have Nginx web server where this minifying application needs mod_rewrite which comes with Apache only. I got this message when I ran the script:

> Your webserver does not seem to support mod_rewrite (used in /min/.htaccess). Your Minify URIs will contain "?", which may reduce the benefit of proxy cache servers.

Now I want to know if there is a way I can use this script on my Nginx server or not? if not, then what would be the alternative to that??

I'm looking for minifying css, js and html that make my web pages fast enough so that my clients can browse my site pages quickly...

any idea?

Thanks

**Update #1:**

I just found out that I had to add a rewrite rule (replacing .htaccess rule) on my nginx server to redirect the folder and its contents.

```
    location / {  

                rewrite ^/min/([a-z]=.*) /min/index.php?$1 last;
}
```

but that redirects to **error 404**... any idea what the correct code is??

Comment: From a user's point of view, minification is barely going to make a difference, and doesn't really have any advantages. I believe it's primary use if for libraries, like jQuery, that get downloaded millions and millions of times per day, saving some data, server-side. That, and obfuscation, of course (Which doesn't benefit the user in any way, either).

Comment: I can't agree with that because the main purpose of minification is to reduce the size and number of static files. besides, it strip white spaces that make a page size a lot smaller, which can be loaded faster. it also reduces the bandwidth.. look here [minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/)

Comment: Even if you strip a thousand spaces from a page, that's just `~1kb`. I'm just saying the advantage is more on the server side. Not saying minification is bad ;-)

Comment: ok, that is at least one point for the server :)

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it is actually correct, the issue that you are having is likely the same one I am (and I'm not sure why it is) but basically it comes down to NGINX's rewrite rules ignoring the ? next to the $1 in the rule.

A work around for this is simply instead of going to `example.com/min/f=path/to/file.css` just put a ? in front of the f `example.com/min/?f=path/to/file.css.`

A better method would be to just serve the files as a group:

> For the best performance you can serve these files as a pre-defined group with a URI like:
>   /min/g=keyName
>
> To do this, add a line like this to /min/groupsConfig.php:

```
return array(
    'keyName' => array('//path/to/js/file.js', '//path/to/js/otherfile.js')
);
```

Chances are though, you may need to use /min/?g=keyName.

As a side note, minifying and bundling isn't `just ~1kb` it can (and tends to be) much more. It has a huge impact on the user (especially on mobile devices). A browser can make 6 concurrent connections, so if you have any more files than that being downloaded, the user is waiting for them, one of the projects I recently have been working on had roughly 60 requests being made for different js and css files (the original coders were... all inclusive in the plugins department). The entire page was roughly 1 Meg and took 3 seconds to download uncached (nothing was cached, because the previous coders don't understand caching). I minified bundled and compressed everything into 3 files (removed the useless stuff too) and got the entire page down to 20kb uncached, 3kb cached, with an uncached load time under 20ms.

That was an extreme example of poor coding though. One final thought... if you don't go into the config and add the cache directories and cache everything, it will cause a slight performance hit on the server (though, probably not as severe as serving up a dozen extra files). I suggest enabling APC or memcache, or at least specifying the cache folder for it to store the files in.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I'm working with old code running minify and have my development server on nginx while the live site is on apache.  I have the min directory located in a subdirectory like mywebsite/register/min/.  So in order to fix this with nginx I had to add the location, modify the try_files section and add a rewrite in my nginx site config file like so...

```
 location /register/min/ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
   rewrite ^/register/min/(.*) /register/min/index.php?$1 permanent;
 }
```

After that, it works great!
I hope this helps anyone else that comes across this!